# PHP is uploading files with no read permissions

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, file-upload, permissions

When uploading images through PHP the resulting file is being created with permissions that don't allow Apache to read the files on later requests. Example permissions for an uploaded file look like this:

```
--w-rw----+  1 www-data www-data 76551 Jan 29 19:52 original.jpeg
```

The permission on the containing folder look like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 41 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 29 19:52 media
```

Apache is running as **www-data** This issue only happens in staging (of course). In my dev environment files upload without issue so it's not likely to be a code issue. I am employing Ubuntu's ACL and I suspect this may have something to do with it.

The result of `getfacl` on the upload directory:

```
# file: web/media
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
user:ubuntu:rwx         #effective:r-x
group::r--
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::-wx
default:user:www-data:rwx 
default:user:ubuntu:rwx
default:group::r-- 
default:mask::rwx
default:other::--x
```

The result of `getfacl` on the file itself:

```
# file: web/media/original.jpeg
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::-w-
user:www-data:rwx       #effective:rw-
user:ubuntu:rwx         #effective:rw-
group::r--
mask::rw-
other::---
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what's php's [umask](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) setting?

Comment: My first thought was to use umask, but you may also try setfacl: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. As suspected it was an ACL issue. The `default:user::-wx` line of the ACL on the upload directory was dictating that new files should be created with `-wx` as the user permission. Running `sudo setfacl -d -m u::rwx <upload dir>` fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

What's your umask?

```
<?php

umask(0022); //unset the write bits, should yield rw-r-r-

//Then your file magic
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```